# Passing a JS array back to controller issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

i have in my view:

```
  <% using (Html.BeginForm("SaveRecommendedUserDetails", "Recommend", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    { %>
     <% foreach (var group in Model.Results)
        { %>       
          <div id="group-select<%: group.GroupId %>" style="width:auto; height:50px; border:solid 1px black; margin:5px;" >
             <h3>&nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="javascript:OnGroupClicked(<%: group.GroupId %>)" id="changer<%: group.GroupId %>"><%: group.Name %></a></h3> 
          </div>
     <% } %>
    {
```

JS:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">   
 function OnGroupClicked(groupId) {
  var groupIds = new Array();
  $("#changer" + groupId).on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var body = $('#group-select' + groupId),
        green = "rgb(0, 128, 0)",
        white = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";

    if (body.css("backgroundColor") !== green) {
      groupIds.push(groupId);
      body.css("backgroundColor", green);
    } else {
      groupIds.pop(groupId);
      body.css("backgroundColor", white);
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

my controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveRecommendedUserDetails(RecommendedUserDataModel model)
    {
      var userId = ZincService.GetUserIdByEmail(model.Email);
      model.UserId = userId;
      ZincService.SaveRecommendedUserDetails(model);
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

RecommendedUserDataModel

```
public class RecommendedUserDataModel
{
  public int UserId { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public string Firstname { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set; }
  public string Department { get; set; }
  public string JobTitle { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<DataModels.Group.GroupDataModel> Groups { get; set; }
 }
```

my problem is that I need to get the groupId back to the controller if it was "selected" thus clicked on. how can I do this please?

Comment: Is your controller getting hit when you placed a debugger inside your action result?

Comment: yes but i need to get in my RecommendedUserDataModel groups the id's of the groups selected so I can save it together with the user details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step3:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">   
  function OnGroupClicked(groupId) {
  var groupIds = new Array();
  $("#changer" + groupId).on("click", function (e) {
      //Here is Step#3
      $('#hdnGroupId').val(groupId+','+$('#hdnGroupId').val());

    });
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it by temporary saving comma seprated group id into a hidden field.
Steps to do that:

1. Add a string Property to your Model like "hdnGroupIds"
2. Put an hidden field into your view under form.
3. Save comma seprated groupID in hdnGroupIds from ajvascript on document.ready and OnGroup Clicked method.

after above steps you can get commaseprated GroupIds into your controller on your post action.